# Is using DateTime.Now really something to worry about?

Tags: c#, performance, datetime

I just read http://aspalliance.com/2062_The_Darkness_Behind_DateTimeNow and started to wonder if this is really something to worry about.. The graph in the article clearly shows that using DateTime.Now is 'much' slower then using DateTime.UtcNow.
Is this graph meaningful for any application you have written? Is this something you noticed yourself? Should I be changing my code not to use DateTime.Now anymore? Basically, have you ever noticed yourself a slowdown by using DateTime.Now?
Can I go sleep without worrying about my miseducation of using DateTime.Now?

Comment: I once had a sleepless night, because every time I called `DateTime.Now` it returned a different value...

Comment: Calling `DateTime.Now` can take hundreds, possibly thousands. of nanoseconds. In the unlikely event that's a problem for you, definitely avoid it.

Comment: Consider that if your app is taking 0.01% of it's time calling `DateTime.Now` optimizing that parts is time that could be spend optimizing more important things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is the answer to any preconceived performance issue, test it.  Does your app call `DateTime.Now` many many times in some performance critical section of code?  If not than I severely doubt it will cause you any appreciable problems, and even if you do you should still test it to see how much slowdown the call causes relative to the entire operation.

Answer (score 2):

No, hasn't impacted any app I've written.  That said, UtcNow is useful beyond perf stuff if you're designing server-based software, since your users may span timezones.

Comment: Not only server stuff. DST can bite you with log files and in plenty of other places as well.